# Are there faster ways to draw than Windows GDI?

Tags: directx, gdi+, gdi

I have been using windows GDI (Gdi32.lib) in C++ language (Visual C++) to draw on a diagram. Actually this is the only knowledge I had about drawing.

When I'm drawing a single diagram with hundreds of GDI functions like ArcTo MoveToEx, the opening on the diagram is slow. This is the problem.

Then came the idea of whether or not I can use CUDA or some techniques to improve the performance.

I'm a beginner. I even don't know how Windows handles it when I call GDI function MoveToEx, in the CPU or Graphic Card.

So could you give me a direction to get me started?

Thank you in advance
Miles

Comment: have you tried creating a memoryDC, drawing all your stuff there and after it's finished throwing it to screen in one swift `Copy`? Drawing directly on the user's screen is never fast.

Comment: @Agent_L Obviously you gave me a good direction, thank you. If possible, could you tell a bit more on how to do this? Especially for "drawing all your stuff there" and "throwing it to screen".

Comment: I wrote an answer about double buffering that might help you with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840464/gdi-acceleration-in-windows-7-drawing-to-memory-bitmap/10841445#10841445

Comment: @milesma Agent_L said memory DC. That should have been enough. Then you Google memory DC and you're set. But your real answer is Direct2D. It'll be a bit complicated for a beginner but it's a starting point. Overly simplified: D2D uses the GPU. GDI uses the CPU. When drawing: GPU good, CPU bad.

Comment: @CodeAngry Actualy, GDI uses hardware acceleration since at least 1990 : ) (as far as OP doesn't venture out to GDI+ which sadly lost the ability)

Comment: @milesma, Redeye said it's called "double buffering" (thanks, I forgot the exact term). Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win-Memory-DC I think it explains a lot for start.

Comment: @Agent_L "GDI maintains its resources, in particular bitmaps, in system memory by default. Direct2D maintains its resources in video memory on the display adapter." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480.aspx Keep reading, it goes intog reat depth. *(maybe I didn't express myself right but that MSDN article should clear things out)*